# Is there a way to trigger callback function just once in $watchGroup | Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm watching two values in my angular project like that: `$scope.$watchGroup( ['currentPage', 'newStatus'], $scope.setPage )`.

And when both values are changing the function $scope.setPage executes two times accordingly, but it should once. How to implement this?

My code:

**JS**

```
app.controller('CategoryListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', function($scope, $http, $location, $route) {
    $scope.numPerPage = 5;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.newStatus = -1;
    var currentPageChanged = false;
    var newStatusChanged = false;

    function setPage() {
        // function's code based on requests to db
    };
    setPage();

    // pagination based on db requests
    $scope.$watchGroup( ['currentPage', 'newStatus'], function(newValues, oldValues) {
        if ((newValues[0] != oldValues[0]) && !newStatusChanged) {
            console.log(1);
            // currentPage has changed
            setPage();
            currentPageChanged = true;
        } else if ((newValues[1] != oldValues[1]) && !currentPageChanged) {
            console.log(2);
            // newStatus has changed
            newStatusChanged = true;
        } else {
            console.log(3);
            newStatusChanged = false;
            currentPageChanged = false;
        }
    });
    ...
```

**HTML**

```
...
<th>
    <select class="form-control"
        ng-model="isPublic"
        ng-options="isPublic.name for isPublic in isPublicScope"
        ng-change="newStatus = isPublic.status; currentPage = 1;">
        <option value="">Show all</option>
    </select>
</th>
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories | filter:search">
</tr>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a flag, which changes when both the values change for the first time (only once). After which you can disable the watch.

Here is an example: [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/detubumisu/1/edit?html,js,output)

can also be written like this: [editted](http://jsbin.com/detubumisu/2/edit?html,js,output)

In this example, two textboxes are given, only when both the textbox values are changed for the first time, the watch increased the count to 1. After that, the watch is disabled and hence the count does not increase even when changes occur in the textboxes.

With a slight change in the code, you may be able to get what you want from this example.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably do the trick (not tested):

```
var w = $scope.$watchGroup( ['currentPage', 'newStatus'],
    function(newValues, oldValues) {
        if ((newValues[0] != oldValues[0]) || (newValues[1] != oldValues[1])) {
          $scope.setPage;
          // clear $watchGroup
          w();
        }

    }
)
```

Comment: Do you have an error to give me so that I can help you ?

Comment: No errors, it just triggers setPage function twice.. Please see the updated question with more details for better understanding the issue.

Comment: I edited my answer, scope.page is only called once then the watch is cleared

Comment: :) no, $scope.setPage() supposed to be called many times. The problem is when both values I watched are changing, the $scope.setPage() executes two times, but it should one. I hope it make sense)